# What data source can be used as the source for steaming service like Event Hubs and Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

From what I read, both event hubs and apache kafka could be used for events steaming, however my question is:
1, ) What sort of data source can be defined as so called 'events' source to use event hubs or apache kafka for?
2, ) In which use case should we use events hubs other than apache kafka, and vice sersa?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Event Hubs is a fully managed event streaming service where as you need to manage an Apache Kafka server. Both products have commonalities and differences, don't really want to list them all here. Here is a good quick read on comparison of both when to choose one over another - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/opensourcemsft/choosing-between-azure-event-hub-and-kafka-what-you-need-to-know

The following scenarios are some of the scenarios where you can use Event Hubs:

- Anomaly detection (fraud/outliers)
- Application logging
- Analytics pipelines, such as clickstreams
- Live dashboarding
- Transaction processing
- User telemetry processing
- Device telemetry streaming

I recommend you to start with this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-about